# Get named variable from list of list

Tags: r

this is probably trivial but can someone help me with this? 
I been using the apply to call a function that returns a list, as such 
`l <- apply(df, 1, manydo)`; manydo function returns a list list("a" = a, "b" = b)

the output l appears to be a list of list, because when I type `str(l)` it returns

```
List of 5
 $ 1:List of 2
  ..$ a: Named num [1:36] 3.29 3.25 3.36 3.26 3.34 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:36] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" ...
  ..$ b: Named num [1:36] 0.659 0.65 0.672 0.652 0.669 ...
```

I tried to access it many ways such as

```
l[1][1]
or l[1]['a']
unlist(l[1][1]['a'])
```

but nothing works. What I want is to be able to get for example, the first element and 'a' variable? 
in addition, if I just call the function directly say:

```
l <- manydo(c(1:36)) # I can access this
l['a'] # this works, so I'm confuse ;(
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` returns a list containing the selected elements.  `[[` returns a single element (not wrapped in a list), so that's what you want to use here.

```
l <- list(list(a=1:10, b=10:22), list(), list(), list(), list())
str(l)
## List of 5
##  $ :List of 2
##   ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
##   ..$ b: int [1:13] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
```

...

Now to retrieve `a`:

```
 l[[1]][['a']]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

`l[[1]]` is the list containing `a`.  `l[[1]][['a']]` is the value of `a` itself.

Comment: this is perfect - thank you for the explanation - been trying this for literally over an hour with no progress until now!